# How to create mention edit text like facebook

Tags: android, android-edittext, mention, facebook-tag

I want to create a edit text where user suggestions will be shown when user typed "@" keyword. 
For eg. If the selected user is: "James test user".
And if user press delete character(back space in android keyboard.) then it should delete the word by word instead of characters. just like first user will be deleted then test and then james.

Any lead will be great for me.
I've tried the https://github.com/linkedin/Spyglass and https://github.com/hendraanggrian/socialview. But they won't fulfill my requirements.